# KQL Search with specific permission

Tags: sharepoint-online, search, permissions, search-results

I want to do a SharePoint (online) search using an user account that has full access but limit the search results by specific rights or groups of users. What is the best way to perform this (except checking every result item permissions to my target group).

Example would be that I have an user Albert that is a site collection administrator and a user Bart that is an user with limited access to some of the libraries on the site. Can I trough code make so that executing the search trough Albert's account he can only see the results that Bart would see.

I need a solution in CSOM but JSOM is also an acceptable alternative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking into it there is no way to make SharePoint filter the items for me and the only solution left is to get all result items and check against the user permissions for the relevant user.

Too bad but not tragic.